# Unknown property using a global gradle variable

Tags: android, maven, gradle, nexus

I'm just upgrade Android Studio to the new stable version:

> Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 Build
> #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023 Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694 amd64

I've got a gradle.properties inside my user folder C:\Users\admin.gradle. This file contains a series of variables that I should use inside my projects.

**gradle.properties**

```
# Global Gradle settings.
#
# Nexus Configuration - Maven repository
domainUser=...
domainPassword=...
domainURLBasic=https://...
domainURLSnapshot=https://...
domainURLRelease=https://...
domainURLThirdParty=https://...
```

After the upgrade, the compilation failed returning me the next error

```
Settings file 'C:\Repositorios\SVN\OPDE_MW\ZeroWord\Android\trunk\zero-word-app\settings.gradle' line: 12

A problem occurred evaluating settings 'zero-word-app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'domainUser' for Credentials [username: null] of type org.gradle.internal.credentials.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated.
```

Can't I use this file globally again? What's wrong?

Thank you for any advice